# IONIC 2 - How can I use app.config.ts declared variables in app.module.ts

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

In my Ionic 2 app I have created app.config.ts file where have declared many variables to use across components like: -

app.config.ts -

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class Config {
    public emailTo = 'sanny@gmail.com';
    public KeyVersion = 1.2;
}
```

In every component I can use it by importing

```
import { Config } from './app.config';
```

Constructor parameter - `private config: Confi`

Calling variable in body - `this.KeyVersion = this.config.KeyVersion;`

This is working fine everywhere in in app.module.ts there is no constructor and when I directly call after import:

```
import { Config } from './app.config';
config.KeyVersion
```

shows error.

How can I use config variables in app.module.ts file?

Thanks Sanny

Comment: Your config should export an constant variable, which could be imported into other files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Three ways:

Create an instance

```
import { Config } from './app.config'
new Config().emailTo
```

Make it static

```
export class Config { 
     public static emailTo = 'sanny@gmail.com'; 
     public static KeyVersion = 1.2; 
}

import { Config } from './app.config'
Config.emailTo
```

Export consts

```
export const emailTo = 'sanny@gmail.com'; 
export const KeyVersion = 1.2; 

import * as Config from './app.config'
Config.emailTo
```